# how can I get url string encoded

Tags: java, url, encoder

I want a url that will look like this

```
"http://example.com/get_item_data.php?uid="inv_no"
```

I tried URL encoder, but could not figure it out,

I first tried this, it did not work

```
try {
   json_url = "http://example.com/get_item_data.php?uid="+  URLEncoder.encode(inv_no, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then this

```
try {
   json_url = "http://example.com/get_item_data.php?uid="+ URLEncoder.encode("inv_no", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(inv_no, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

yet, no result, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you don't have to quote your parameters. So to me your first trial is correct:

```
   json_url = "http://example.com/get_item_data.php?uid="+ 
                  URLEncoder.encode( inv_no, "UTF-8");
```

Not sure about what you're trying to do, but looking at your question I suggest the following code:

```
try {
   json_url = "http://example.com/get_item_data.php?uid=\""+ 
                  URLEncoder.encode( inv_no, "UTF-8") + "\"";
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this case you have the quote outside the encoded parameter `inv_no`.

Or even:

```
try {
   json_url = "http://example.com/get_item_data.php?uid="+ 
                  URLEncoder.encode("\"" + inv_no + "\"", "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this case the parameter `inv_no` and the quotes will be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the whole string AFTER you added your ´inv_no´-variable.

`try {
    json_url = URLEncoder.encode('http://example.com/get_item_data.php?uid='+inv_no, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
       String    json_url = "\"http://example.com/get_item_data.php?uid=\"inv_no\"";
     System.out.println(json_url);  
     } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```